# Casear Cipher Brute force attack - every possible key

Tags: encryption

I need help with my code. I have to find out every possible key in Ceaser cipher. I have upper a lower letters in my message and nothing else. But my keys are repeating in my code, but I need every key unique. Pls help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char cryptedText[]; //here could be any crypted text

int main()
    {
        for (int key = 0; key <= 52; ++key)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cryptedText); ++i)
                {
                    if (cryptedText[i] >= 'A' && cryptedText[i] <= 'Z')
                    {
                        printf("%c", ((cryptedText[i] - 'A' + key)%26 + 'A'));
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        printf("%c", ((cryptedText[i] - 'a' + key)%26 + 'a'));
                    }
                }

            printf("Number of key %d\n", key);
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some way of keeping track of what keys you have already extracted.  Maybe store them in a set, which is designed to only store unique values.  Then you can print out all the values from the set at the end.